# Solr: match results with and without whitespaces

Tags: java, filter, lucene, solr, analyzer

The data in our solr field looks like this:

```
<str name="property_Info_Hd">320 GB SATA 7200RPM</str>
<str name="property_Info_Hd">320GB SATA</str>

<str name="property_Info_Memory">4 GB of DDR2</str>
<str name="property_Info_Memory">2GB of DDR3</str>
```

The field is dynamic ("property_*"), so both cases use the same analyzer.

Currently, when searching for "2gb", it returns documents with "2GB" but misses "2 GB" (whitespace).

Question is: how could I set this field type in schema so it **matches results with and without whitespaces**?

For example:

Searching for +(property_Info_Memory:("320gb")) should return both the first lines above, matching "320GB" **AND** "320 GB".

This is how the field type is set:

```
<fieldType name="textFilter" class="solr.TextField" 
        positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                splitOnCaseChange="0" 
                splitOnNumerics="0" 
                stemEnglishPossessive="0" 
                catenateWords="1" 
                catenateNumbers="1" 
                catenateAll="1" 
                preserveOriginal="1" 
                generateWordParts="1" 
                generateNumberParts="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory" />
       </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I've tried using splitOnCase and splitOnNumerics variations, none succeeded. Results then would match the ones with whitespaces (320 GB) and miss the non-whitespaced ones (320GB).

Most documents have it's data without whitespaces, thats why the current setup.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two ways to accomplish this:

1. Have two fields store the data, each tokenized in a different way (i.e. use a copy field)
2. Have one field with a custom synonym filter

#2 is the better solution, but will require writing some java. I'd recommend just extending the WordDeliminterFilter; you can see the source of SynonymTokenFilter for how to create synonyms.

Comment: The copy field solution was our first option, but we would then need to re-index all products documents so the new field could appear. Since our catalog is huge, that ain't viable. As for the synonym, we could work on that approach but it would require some effort we can't afford right now. But thats indeed one possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I lost track of time. Better late than ever, I ended up using your solution: having two fields to store the data, each tokenized in a different way (using copy field).

We choose to re-index one product category (departament) at a time, eventualy becoming viable. 

Thanks!

Comment: @leovrf I'm trying to solve a similar problem in Hibernate Search. The  problem I have though is I'm using `StandardTokenizerFactory` for tokenizing. At that point, a word such as '320 GB' will be tokenized as '320 and 'GB'. Do you know of a way to have it so the tokens will become '320', 'GB' AND '320GB'?

Answer (score 4):

Worked from the analysis tool. you may want to give it a try :-

```
<fieldType name="textFilter" class="solr.TextField" 
        positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                catenateWords="1" 
                catenateNumbers="1" 
                catenateAll="1" 
                preserveOriginal="1" 
                generateWordParts="1" 
                generateNumberParts="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
       </analyzer>  
       <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                splitOnNumerics="1" 
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
       </analyzer>  
 </fieldType>
```

Analysis -

Index time - 2gb of data

Query time - 2gb
Tokens - 2gb, 2 gb

2 gb is generated as a token in the analysis and it shows a match in the index.

Comment: Tried but unfortunately it didn't work. Whitespaces results matched, but not the concatenated words (ones that matters the most). Your suggestion made me realize I needed to change the index analyzer, so it was helpfull :)

Comment: can you check on admin analysis cause this worked fine for me? check the outputs in verbose ? What query are you trying ?

Comment: Field value: "2gb". The three query filters returned two terms: 1 - "2" ; 2 - "gb". Its a big query, involving products departments, availability, and so on. The hard disk and/or memory fields are applied to filter querys. Does it change your analysis?

Comment: Updated with analysis. I tested for both 2 GB and 2GB in index and on search and all checks match. Are you using the product fields in search ? or a generic field with other field type ?